# Which credit card processors support deferred payment processing

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, payment-processing

I'm looking for a payment proceessor which accepts credit cards and also supports deferred processing. To be clear my ideal workflow is:

- user commits to buy
- user is redirected to processor site and enters details
- authorization is returned to my site
- my site waits for up to 24hrs
- payment authorization is used to debit user's card/account

Please one site per answer so the best ones can be voted up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorize.Net allows you to perform an AUTH_ONLY which allows you to freeze the funds on a user's card. Then when you are ready to capture payment you do a PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE indicating the transaction ID to receive the frozen funds. The user's credit card is not needed for the second part.

They also offer the CIM API which let's you create payment profiles for your customers. Then you can charge their card whenever you want without the customer's card being present.

Comment: Is AUTH_ONLY transaction available for capture after more than 24 hours? They say about 30 days in docs. Can I really capture transaction after 29 days, regardless of client's bank?

Answer (score 1):

[authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/) is a popular payment gateway. I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but take a look at the [CC Transaction Types](http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/Submitting_Transactions/Credit_Card_Transaction_Types.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place a "hold" on an amount of money.

The transaction is approved and the money is taken off the card holders available balance, but no actual transfer takes place.

At some later time you can either execute or cancel the "hold". If you do nothing the hold will be released after some time (days) has elapsed.

You will need a prior agreement with your "merchant acquirer" -- i.e. your bank -- in order to execute these transactions.

This is the mechanism used by care hire companies to make sure you can pay the rental and any damages when you return the car, and, hotels to make sure they get paid if you decide on "death by minibar".

Comment: Yes, but which payment processors support performing this?

Comment: Exactly how many days "holded" transaction is available for capture? [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization_hold) tells it can be as short as 1 day. So there is no guarranteed way to "hold" for, say, 20 or 40 days?